# Is it possible to include a hyperlink in a Facebook private message?

Tags: facebook, links

Is it possible to include a hyperlink in a Facebook private message? I only see text without clikkable link.

Comment: Did you remember to include the `http://`?

Answer (score 2):

Prefix http:// with your url to make that as clickable link ( `<a>` ) and display preview